# How to get the sanitized value (the html string) from SafeHtml object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using the DomSanitizer function bypassSecurityTrustHtml() for sanitizing.

Comment: How can we help you with no code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

The value is stored in a `changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity` property. Which probably says enough to not use it.

```
const safeHtml = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<div>hello</div>');
const html = safeHtml['changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity'];
// html === <div>hello</div>;
```

However, you should only use the sanitizer and the value returned inside your template:

```
<div [innerHTML]="safeHtml"></div>
```

Now the div will have the contents of the html passed into the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`

Comment: Tnx, i thought there must be some more comlicated way to get the value :)
I'm sending that value to the api, so it can be saved in the db.